# Blank screen when I use FineUI MVC Grid Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently download FineUI free trial package, and try to use their grid control in my new project. I made new project, I didn't have any problem when use traditional MVC framework from asp.net. But I want to use FineuiMVC grid in my project to save some development effort.

I already added Fineuimvc.dll to my project. However, I see error
[image]

After some research, I realize adding @using FineuiMvc can resolve above issue. But I still see an empty screen. The view HTML source code looks like below

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid/CheckAll - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <!--##FineUIMvc.RenderCssExtension##-->
    <link href="/res/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  ....
    <!--##FineUIMvc.RenderScriptExtension##-->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="/res/js/grid.js"></script>
  ....
  </html>
```

I notice there are two placeholders in the HTML source code, but not sure the root cause. Does any one know this if you are using FineUI control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. using FineUIMvc

To avoid write "using FineUIMvc" on every view, you need update the Views/Web.config to add FineUIMvc namespace under <system.web.webPages.razor> section. One example is

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="FineUIMvc" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

2. Managed pipeline mode

Please double check your project setting. If you are using **Integrated** mode, please change the configuration to below

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
    <add name="FineUIMvcScriptModule" type="FineUIMvc.ScriptModule, FineUIMvc"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
    <add name="FineUIMvcResourceHandler" verb="GET" path="res.axd" type="FineUIMvc.ResourceHandler, FineUIMvc"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

For **Classic** mode, it is using <system.web> tag.

BTW, http://mvc.fineui.us/ has examples for your reference.

Hope above explanation can help you out.